# Annoying black color appears on beamer block after some edits

Tags: beamer, block

Here's my problem:

[image]

You see the black color there around my block? I don't know why this happened. I want to remove it. By the way since ths beamer requires a picture. Please use any picture and rename it "`logo.png`". Hope you want to help me. Thanks!

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\beamertemplateshadingbackground{yellow!30!white}{cyan!20!white} 
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{contour}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SET BEAMER FONT ON BLOCK %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\small}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   SET THE INNER MARGIN OF BLOCKS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}
{}
{\vspace{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex} % Pads top of block
    % separates paragraphs in a block
    \setlength{\parskip}{24pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-.2cm}{.3cm}
    }
    \addtobeamertemplate{block end}
    {\end{adjustwidth}%
    \vspace{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}}% Pads bottom of block
{\vspace{10ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}} % Seperates blocks from each other
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% Set Color ==============================

% Custom colors
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}


\colorlet{titleleft}{red!70!white} %Ganti warna gradasi kiri pada judul section
\colorlet{titleright}{cyan!70!white} %Ganti warna gradasi kanan pada judul section

% http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm
\definecolor{gold}{HTML}{FDD017}
\definecolor{deep sky blue}{HTML}{3BB9FF}
\definecolor{light sky blue}{HTML}{82CAFA}

\definecolor{mybackground}{HTML}{82CAFA}
\definecolor{myforeground}{HTML}{0000A0}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=myforeground, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{background}{fg=myforeground, bg=mybackground}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black, bg=gray!50!white} %Ganti warna bar pojok kanan bawah
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=black, bg=gray!20!white}%Ganti warna bar tengah bawah
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black, bg=red!70!white}%Ganti warna bar pojok kiri bawah

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white} %Ganti warna tulisan pada frame judul
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white} %Ganti warna tulisan pada judul
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure, bg=red} %Ganti warna pada kotak judul

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{subsection in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% GLOBAL SETTING OF ITEMSEP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\define@key{beamerframe}{wide}[5pt]{%
    \def\beamer@cramped{\itemsep #1\topsep0.5pt\relax}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mydefault}[1][]
{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begin{centering}
        {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
            %           \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
            \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
            \else%
            %           \vskip0.25em%
            {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
            \fi%     
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \vskip1em\par
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
            \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
            \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
            \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
        \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    \end{centering}
    \vfill
}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[mydefault][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
    color(0pt)=(titleleft);
    color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{horizontal shading}
{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    %\vskip-2pt%
    \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
                    \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
                    \leftskip0.3cm%
                    \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
                    \insertframetitle%
                    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                    \strut\par%
                    \else
                    \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
                    \fi%
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \vbox{}%
            \end{minipage}}%
            \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
            \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                \pgfusepath{clip}
                \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
            \end{pgfpicture}
            \hskip-\paperwidth%
            \box\beamer@tempbox%
        }%
        \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
    }%
    \vskip-2pt
}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=.33\paperwidth]{white-logo}{}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=.33\paperwidth]{large-corner}{large-corner}


\newcommand\DoPurpleBackground{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{-\paperheight}}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{cyan!70!white}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{-\paperheight},right,base]{\pgfuseimage{large-corner}}
}
\newenvironment{myfont1}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}{\par}
\newenvironment{myfont2}{\fontfamily{uncl}\selectfont}{\par}

\newcommand\ThankYouFrame{
    \begin{frame}[plain,t]
        \transboxout<1>[duration=2]
        \begin{pgfpicture}
            \pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse
            \pgftransformxshift{-\Gm@lmargin}
            \pgftransformyshift{5.5pt}
            \DoPurpleBackground
            \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{.5\paperwidth}{-.52\paperheight},center,center]{\pgfuseimage{white-logo}}
            \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{.5\paperwidth}{-.23\paperheight},center,center]{
                \begin{myfont1}
                    \fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont\contour{yellow}{\color{red}Terima Kasih}
                \end{myfont1}
            }
            \pgftext[at=\pgfpoint{.5\paperwidth}{-.8\paperheight},center,center]{
                \begin{myfont2}
                    \small\structure{Universitas Jember}
                \end{myfont2}
            }
        \end{pgfpicture}
    \end{frame}
}

\makeatother

% Set Color ==============================

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% GANTI NAMA & JUDUL & DLL %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Title}
\subtitle{\textbf{Another Title}}
\author[Me]{My Name is Who?}
\institute[FOO]{Institue \\ Insitute \\Insitute \\ Insitute}

\date{\today}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{logo}\vspace*{.5cm}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
    
    %   \frame{\maketitle}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \section[Outline]{}
    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
        \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.85\textwidth, -1cm)
            \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{logo}
        \end{textblock*}
    }
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \transboxin<1>[duration=2]
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[wide]{THIS IS WHAT}
        \transpush<1>
        \setbeamercovered{transparent}
        \setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue!80!black}
        \setbeamercolor{block body example}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=blue!10!white}
        \onslide<+->{\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true]{block title example}
                LIPSUM
        \end{beamercolorbox}}
        \onslide<+->{\begin{exampleblock}{LIPSUM}
                \justifying
                LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM LIPSUM
        \end{exampleblock}}
    \end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

**Edit :**

Since @Werner and @schoekling said they didn't have this problem, i'm assumming there's something wrong with my code that might works in one device but not in another. I say this because i still have the problem even after i use another TeX editor, TeXmaker, (Currently i'm using TeXstudio latest version). So, please can you answer my question by providing the alternative for `beamorcolorbox`? I want a blue block. Thank you so much!

Comment: When I compile your example I don't see a black block ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laJL0.png)).

Comment: @Werner hmm.. it's weird. Actually i'm pretty sure i never edited the beamer or did i? i'm not sure. And this file has been around for a few months ago. This happened after i update my TeXstudio. What's the problem.?

Comment: I don't see a black block either, but there are some artifacts in TeXstudio's viewer, which however vary depending on zoom factor etc. Does the box in your case show the same behavior?

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whk1R.png) btw is the type of artifact I mentioned

Comment: how are you compiling? with xelatex? And which texsystem do you use? (The block typically appears with some ghostscript versions)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i'm pretty sure, i'm using pdflatex. I don't know what happens.

Comment: Check your log file. It tells you what you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade to a recent version of the beamer package. With version `2021/03/19 v3.62` (as e.g. included in TeXLive 2021) the problem vanishes. The relevant fix happens in file `beamerbaseboxes.sty`.

With a slightly older version, `2020/11/26 v3.60`, I can reproduce the problem. It occurs under the following conditions:

- Use of a box with rounded corners and shadows
- The box is uncovered, e.g. with `\pause`
- The color of hidden elements is set to transparent.

Here is a rather minimal example showing the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text
\pause
\begin{block}{Block title}
  Block text.
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can still reproduce that problem [the minimal example] with beamer 2022/02/08 v3.66 when I run latex+dvips+ps2pdf. Actually, even the light gray part of the first overlay is black for me. Looks like the problem comes from MiKTeX which still uses the 2018 version 9.25 of gs. I posted that in their github <https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1070> now, maybe it'll change...

Comment: MiKTeX or more?  With cygwin gs, ps2pdf I obtained a PDF reporting "GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0", yet still with the same problem.

Comment: See github [Isse 275](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/275), that seems to a more appropriate place for continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I commented:

%\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

And the problem was solved.

Comment: This line isn't in the original example so I'm not sure you were experiencing the same problem. If you mean you commented a line in another file, you'd need to explain exactly what you did to fix the OP's problem (and not just one a bit like it).