# Black frame in block in Beamer

Tags: beamer, block

I am trying to prepare a presentation with Beamer. I have two laptops one of them is a 2015 MacBook Air i7 and the other one is a MacBook Air M2. I am using TexShop with the same version, version 5.12, on both laptops.  On my old laptop everything works fine but on the new one, when I tried to write something in the block environment a black frame appear on the blocks, see first photo. I tried many things but couldn't find a solution. By the way in the log file, I have the following error message: %%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY. I also searched a solution for this error but couldn't find one being applicable to the TexShop. Is there anyone have an idea about this problem? Thank you in advance.

Ps: If I typeset the file with LuaLaTeX it works without the black frame. But in this case, the universal letters (Turkish letters in my case) do not appear in the dvi. Is there any solution to show accent letters in LuaLaTeX?

Edit: I am using MacTeX April version. I checked the TeX Live Utility and its version is 1.54. Below, I present the commands which produce the first photo I gave.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary{use=structure,fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=structure!75,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=structure!75,fg=white}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,turkish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{block}{balabal}
 blabala
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I typeset the same codes with LuaLaTeX I obtain the second photo.

Interestingly now only some Turkish characters, ı,ş etc., do not appear and some, ü, ç, etc,  appear.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DCuR.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUYgl.png

Comment: How do you compile your document?

Comment: It would also be nice if you could mention which version of texlive you have installed and add a short but compilable test document which reproduces your problems with Turkish letters.

Comment: I am away from the laptop now. I will post as soon as possible.

Comment: I guess this is a problem of a beamer package dated 2020 or earlier, see [Annoying black color appears on beamer block after some edits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593207/110998). Upgrading the package or the whole TeX distro should fix the issue.

Comment: @Banx Which tools do you use to compile your code? Do you compile via `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`? If yes try with `ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` instead

Comment: Actually, in TexShop I don't know how to change ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY. When I check the option of the TexShop Tex+DVI is selected in Typesetting. If I change it to pdftex it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with `lualatex`, remove the `fontenc` package to get your Turkish letters.

(... and the closing `}` after `{palette tertiary` is missing)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=structure!75,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=structure!75,fg=white}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,turkish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

Interestingly now only some Turkish characters, ı,ş etc., do not appear and some, ü, ç, etc, appear.

\begin{block}{balabal}
 blabala
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. In the original file, I have the missing "}" palette tertiary. It works correctly with LuaLaTeX now. But still, I don't understand why it doesn't work on one laptop, but, works with the other one while compiling via LaTeX.

Comment: @Banx I suspect that on your one laptop, you have an old version of ghostscript, which is used when converting from ps to pdf if you compile with via the dvi route. In this old ghostscript version, transparency was allowed by default. In newer gs version, transparency is off by default for security reasons. This is why new versions need to be called need to be called with the `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` option. If you use pdflatex, lualatex etc. you don't have this intermediate step and directly compile to pdf, thus you don't run into problems with ghostscript.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Probably it is the reason. Because I also updated Ghostscript via Terminal on the new laptop. Do you know any way to allow -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY option for MacBook maybe using Terminal?

Comment: @Banx You need to configure texshop to run `dvips` with the `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` option (... or whatever other tools are used in this `TexShop Tex+DVI` procedure....)